# Spyder 4 is not displaying plots and displays message like this 'uncheck "Mute Inline Plotting" under the Plots pane options menu.'

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, ipython, spyder

I wrote this code. It should display the plots in spyder ide.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import scipy.signal
import scipy.stats
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", nrows=9000000,dtype={'acoustic_data':np.int16,'time_to_failure':np.float64})

train.rename({"acoustic_data": "signal", "time_to_failure": "quaketime"}, axis="columns", inplace=True)      

#visualization(train,title="Acoustic data and time to failure: sampled data")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(20,12))
ax[0].plot(train.index.values, train.quaketime.values, c="darkred")
ax[0].set_title("Quaketime of 10 Mio rows")
ax[0].set_xlabel("Index")
ax[0].set_ylabel("Quaketime in ms")
ax[1].plot(train.index.values, train.signal.values, c="mediumseagreen")
ax[1].set_title("Signal of 10 Mio rows")
ax[1].set_xlabel("Index")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Acoustic Signal")
```

Spyder IDE dispaly following message instead of plot

> Figures now render in the Plots pane by default. To make them also
>   appear inline in the Console, uncheck "Mute Inline Plotting" under the
>   Plots pane options menu.

I have tested this code in google colab. It plots the required graph. How I can plot in Spyder IDE.
I am using Spyder 4.0.1. I did not found any "Mute Inline Plotting" option to uncheck

Comment: By following exactly what it's telling you

Comment: I did not find "Mute Inline Plotting" option in spyder ide

Comment: One should also verify if the "Plots" pane is visible. Go to View -> Panes and check the "Plots" case.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you have is neither an error nor a warning. It's an instruction. You can find the options following:

[image]

Ignore the console outputs, that's just to give you orientation in Spyder 4.0.1.

Comment: If it's not a warning, why does it display with a big orange banner that says "Warning"? (I'm using Spyder 5.0.5.)

Comment: @Ilya no idea. Perhaps because my answer was about Spyder 4