# i write that code with python using the library pandas and i had no errors and no results please can you help me , the result must be a graph

Tags: python, pandas

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series((3,6,9,8,5,4,2,6,3,5,8))

data.plot()
data.plot(kind='line')
```

Comment: Hi emma, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please elaborate on the issue you're facing; what exactly are your expected results? Does anything happen when you run the code? What have you tried? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65363047/edit) your question to include more details.

Comment: You never displayed the plot.  That's what `show` does.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You need to make sure you've followed the existing documentation before you post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my previous post:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.Series((3,6,9,8,5,4,2,6,3,5,8))

plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

(I deleted the previous post to avoid confusion)

Comment: it doesnt work for me and i have no result no errors !

Comment: what are you using? Jupyter Notebook or running a script? Can you test that it runs by just printing some text?

Comment: i use spyder like ide ; spyder it works with the others codes but for that one no i dont know why ?

Comment: Hmm I just tried Spyder 3.3.6 and copied and pasted that code but I can see the result. Can you try the advice on this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769492/spyder-4-is-not-displaying-plots-and-displays-message-like-this-uncheck-mute-i

Comment: yes finally its work ,thank youuu !

Answer (score 0):

You need to import matplotlib as well

```py
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.Series((3,6,9,8,5,4,2,6,3,5,8))

data.plot(kind='line')
```